# How to add a Dropdown item on the action bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, android-spinner

In my Android Honeycomb application I use Tabs as the navigation style. I would like to add one item next to the overflow button, but I want that item to be a dropdown list, and the user will be able to select an option there, but not related to navigation. What is the easiest way since I'm using `mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);`

Is it possible to do it without using a custom view?

Comment: Check the 4 link : These links help for you http://fizzylogic.azurewebsites.net/2012/03/05/mono-for-android-by-example-the-action-bar/ https://github.com/StylingAndroid/StylingActionBar https://github.com/StylingAndroid/BasicActionBar

Answer (score 223, accepted):

**First option:**

menu/options.xml:

```
<item
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_sort"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuSortNewest"
            android:title="Sort by newest" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuSortRating"
            android:title="Sort by rating" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

**Second option:**

menu/options.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuSort"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_sort"  />
</menu>
```

layout/action_sort.xml:

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_menu_refresh"
    android:entries="@array/order" />
```

Docs for menu resources - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: Great answer! Btw., you can also include icons in the submenu.

Comment: how do I respond to a click of the spinner?

Comment: This does not work for Android 2.2. The app is crashing. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Use ActionBarSherlock...they hadn't introduced ActionBar back in Android 2.2 and therefore ActionBarSherlock allows you to back date these features. http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: Is it possible to set customLayout and Submenu at the same time, Im trying it for long time

Comment: what happen if you are in tab navigation mode?

Comment: what is '@array/order' this here and what we can add?

Comment: Thank you very much,Working fine, But my question is how to handle OnItemSelectedListener for this spinner?

Comment: @Sandeep Maram You can get spinner by `Spinner spinner = (Spinner)menu.findItem(R.id.menuPeriodType).getActionView()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. Then set the item select listener.

Comment: The first option doesn't seem to work as of Android 7.0.

Answer (score 35):

Absolutely the best and and the simplest answer I found so far is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22901703/202166).

Basically, no need for custom layout in this case. Just set the actonViewClass:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

  <item android:id="@+id/spinner"
    yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" /> <== this is all that's required
</menu>
```

And then handle it in onCreateOptionsMenu, as usual:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item); // get the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
```

This is by far the simplest and cleanest solution. Credits to François Poyer, the original author.

Comment: Tested and approved.

Answer (score 0):

It will work as dropdown only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <!--<item-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/save_contact"-->
    <!--android:icon="@drawable/edit_new"-->
    <!--android:title="Save Contact"-->
    <!--app:showAsAction="never" />-->

    <item
        android:id="@+id/send_money"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit_new"
        android:title="Send Money"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/request_money"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit_new"
        android:title="Request money"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/recharge"
        android:icon="@drawable/edit_new"
        android:title="Recharge"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

inside fragment

setHasOptionsMenu(true)

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.chat_details_menu, menu);


    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```