# ActionBar menu inflation error from SherlockFragment (ClassCastException)

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, classcastexception

I'm trying to use the solution of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar), in order to have a Spinner in my ActionBar.
I was first using the NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST of the ActionBar, but I don't want the spinner to be used to navigate trough views (I will have tabs for that).
So I've created 2 xml :

mode_spinner.xml

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

options.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_mode"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/mode_spinner"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

and then, tried to inflate it from my fragment (SherlockFragment)

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options, menu);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_mode);
    spinner.setAdapter(mSpinnerAdapter);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

at runtime, I got this error :

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapper cannot be cast to android.widget.Spinner

any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to call `getActionView()` on the resulting item returned from `findItem()` to access that view. From there you can manipulate it.

You may also want to consider simply using a sub-menu with exclusively checkable items.

Comment: thank you so much !
here is the corrected line:   

`Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_mode).getActionView();`