# Collapsed MenuItem never expands in ActionMode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I have an Item in my Action Bar (ActionBarCompat) that appears in Action mode and should display a Spinner with some options.

The code looks like:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit_context_actions"
    android:title="@string/edit_context_actions"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_actions"
    glarm:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    android:visible="true"
    glarm:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
```

The Spinner is added in the following way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.edit_context_menu, menu);

    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377760/adding-spinner-to-actionbar-not-navigation/11720767#11720767
    Spinner actionSpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.edit_context_actions));
    actionSpinner.setAdapter(new ActionSpinnerAdapterImpl2(getActivity(), mActionList));
    actionSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnActionSelectionListener());

    return true;
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the collapsed icon, the Spinner never expands.
What am I doing wrong?