# Custom Action Bar not inflating

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-xml

I'm trying to make a custom action, but it's not working. I followed the instructions of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518414/how-can-i-implement-custom-action-bar-with-custom-buttons-in-android) post almost to the dot, but it's not working. Here's the layout file for my action bar (`action_bar_tablet.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
android:padding="16dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="The Commuter"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="24sp"
    android:entries="@string/lines"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And here's the `MainActivity` method that I use to inflate it:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
        TABLET = false;

        //...

    } else {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            TABLET = true;

            //...

            final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                    R.layout.action_bar_tablet,
                    null);
            final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

        }
    }
}
```

This seems so simple, but I'm not sure why it's not working. Could someone please help me out?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:

Here's the `string.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">The Commuter Chicago</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="lines">Lines</string>
<string name="stops">Stops</string>
<string name="arrivals">Arrivals</string>
<string-array name="lines">
    <item>Red</item>
    <item>Blue</item>
    <item>Brown</item>
    <item>Green</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Purple</item>
    <item>Pink</item>
    <item>Yellow</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Comment: Are you trying to put a spinner in your action bar?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to do that.

Comment: can you post your strings.xml?

Comment: @DanielNugent I added an edit.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm trying to see if I can get this to work.  I also found these posts:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377760/adding-spinner-to-actionbar-not-navigation    and this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar

Comment: Your Mainactivity extends from `ActionbarActivity` or `Activity`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try this if your `Activity` is `ActionBarActivity`

```
 @Override  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)   { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_pager_and_easmain);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);

 getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.action_bar_tablet);
```

and change your code to checking condition of

```
if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {
```

don't check it just initialize your Actionbar after setContent() method.

Comment: Just needed to use getSupportActionBar() instead of what I have! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
Dear change your code and fellow this.  
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActionBar mActionBar = getActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.fr`enter code here`om(this);
        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(action_bar_tablet, null);
        TextView mTitleTextView = (TextView) <br>             mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        mTitleTextView.setText("My Own Title");

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    }
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android
```