# Custom spinner not showing dropdown in ActionBar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner, android-menu

Trying to get my custom Spinner with only an ImageView (to show a list of icon drawables) to work. I thought I had the custom adapter code correct, and the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` code correct, but no. The icon for the sharing feature shows in the ActionBar, but when I touch it, the Spinner does not dropdown the menu it should. What could be wrong? This goal is unique, because it is not just a custom spinner (easy to find tutorial on) or just an ActionBar icon placement (also easy), but rather combining them both, which is hard to find resources on.

[image]

**PhotoViewerActivity.java**

```
package org.azure_simbiosys.cutecollection.phototab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

import org.azure_simbiosys.R;

public class PhotoViewerActivity extends ActionBarActivity
                                implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    private ArrayAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    int[] iconList = {R.drawable.ic_facebook, R.drawable.ic_twitter, R.drawable.ic_sms};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_viewer);

        // Shows the up carat near app icon in ActionBar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ImageView photoView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.photo_display);

        // gets the single bitmap image from the array of bytes
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        byte[] byteArray = extras.getByteArray("photo");
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);

        // sets device orientation based on the image orientation
        if (bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight()){
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        } else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        // sets bitmap into your ImageView
        photoView.setImageBitmap(bm);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        // Facebook, Twitter, SMS code here

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    private class ShareSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

        // constructor
        public ShareSpinnerAdapter (Context context, int iconResourceId){

            super(context, iconResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            View itemView = convertView;

            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {

            return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
            View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.share_spinner_row, parent, false);

            ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.spinner_icon);
            icon.setImageResource(iconList[position]);

            return row;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_share, menu);

        Spinner shareSpinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.action_social_share).getActionView();

        spinnerAdapter = new ShareSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.share_spinner_row);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        shareSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        shareSpinner.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_social_share));

        // add listener
        shareSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Makes the UP caret go back to the previous fragment MakeCuteHome
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                android.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                fm.popBackStack();
                finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_social_share:


                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

**menu_share.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Share, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_social_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_social_share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/action_share"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"/>

</menu>
```

**action_share.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/share_spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**share_spinner_row**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want share icon on action bar work as a spinner... then create child of item tag in menu_share.xml file as..

```
 <item android:id="@+id/menu"
      android:icon="@drawable/menu"
      android:title="menu"

      android:showAsAction="always" >


      <menu>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Login"
        android:title="Login"
        android:icon="@drawable/contact" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:title="Share"
        android:icon="@drawable/share" />
     <item
        android:id="@+id/like"
        android:title="Like"
        android:icon="@drawable/favourite" />
</menu>

    </item>
```

Comment: this is just an example...try this

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but the parent <item> is red. It says element item must be declared.

Comment: Have you put the parent item also in a menu tag?

Comment: I tried, but I'm not really sure why this will work, can you explain? I only need one item (share) and you put 3 items. Also, what am I to use for the parent item icon? I already have the icon I need in the share <item> tags. It doesn't make sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: You want when you click on share icon..Spinner will open...isn'i it?

Comment: Yes. I was looking for an detailed, explicit answer. That's ok. Even if I don't understand, I still don't know what to do with the parent item drawable.

Comment: Okay, this code will place a white boxed word (whatever is set as the title) when I touch the icon in the ActionBar, but it does not include all the other items that integrate with my array list of drawables. It's more of a hack to just get items to appear in the icon (which could come in handy for other projects I'm sure), but it ignores all the other code in my activity that I definitely need to use. So, I can't use this. Plus the drawables did not show up, only the titles.