# ABS CustomView - overflow menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, custom-view, oncreateoptionsmenu

I'm working on a project where I need to replace the ABS with an **customview**. I have a button on the top right corner. When you click that button I want a Spinner/contextMenu/overflow menu shown (like the standard abs with overflow theme).

The button will trigger the **onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)** to be called

Untill now I only managed to get the menu on the bottom of the activity (contextmenu) with following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu){
   menu.add(Menu.None, "", Menu.None, "title").setShowAsAction     (MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);


   menu.add(Menu.None, "", Menu.None, "title").setShowAsAction     (MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_NEVER);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

After doing some research I found that PopUpMenuHelper could help me, but if fail to find some samples/examples.

Has someone done something similair? Any tips? Any libraries or classes that I could use?

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Overflow menu will only appear if the device hasn't got hardware keys. If it has got, the menu will appear like a standard popup menu at the bottom.

Comment: If you think this is the answer for your question, please mark as answer.

Comment: I dont want the standard overflow menu, i want custom contextMenu that looks like the overflow menu (same place, size,.. etc)

Comment: So you want to do this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223283/custom-drop-down-from-action-item-actionbarsherlock) ?