# How to create a action bar with drop down like the one in Android Google Calender App?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

how to create a action bar like the one in Google Calender App which has a button clicking on which a drop down appears occupying the complete parent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: How want to how do I display a layout as a extension of the action bar as in the Google Calender app  when user clicks drop down button . Here is a link to image in Calender app .[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w4d6llkpq741jxj/Screenshot_2015-05-07-11-48-20.png?dl=0)

Comment: check this site as they explain everything about action bar including your need (http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar hope it help :)

Answer (score 0):

Google Calender app uses custom view as an action bar.

You can define any view as an action bar. For more details just check this link.

http://javatechig.com/android/actionbar-with-custom-view-example-in-android