# How do I place icon in upper left of Activity titlebar?

Tags: android

I would like to place icon is upper left corner of Activity title bar. Also how do I widen the activity title bar?  Thanks  Is it possible to have button on left side that is menu so when you click it has menu item like logoff?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using toolbar it is done like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Comment: Ok, do you know how I could have a dropdown from there?

Comment: you can have dropdown in overflow menu using menu.xml...goto menu.xml and add list same as settings in menu.xml....

Answer (score 1):

In your Action bar what you can do is

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

and also you can set the logo in your manifest file

In AndroidManifest.xml add line:

```
android:logo="@drawable/icon"
```

Comment: How about a dropdown menu on left hand side?  What's involved in that?

Comment: @MuayThai for that have a look at this link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar