# Spinner not appearing in the menu bar

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a spinner item in my menu bar via XML. My code is as follows,

**res/layout/spinner_filter_results.xml**

```
<Spinner xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/results_filters"/>
```

**res/menu/menu_results.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Spinner not showing up -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menuFilter"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/spinner_filter_results"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/iconHamburger"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/options">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
                android:title="@string/settings"
                android:onClick="onMenuItemClick"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:title="@string/log_out"
                android:onClick="onMenuItemClick"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

This shows up fine in the Android Studio designer, this is exactly what I want:

[image: Menu bar in Android Studio]

But on my phone it doesn't show up.

[image: Menu bar on phone]

I've looked to other Stack Overflow posts such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar), but I still can't figure out why the above code doesn't work. Does anyone have any insight as to why it doesn't show up on my phone? Is this just a problem of my phone?(LG G4, Android 6.0, SDK 23)

**EDIT 1:**
I turned on Show Layout Bounds on my phone. I see that the Menu item for the Spinner exists but it seems to be empty?

[image: Empty Menu Item]

Comment: Did You add the adapter to the spinner with items to display? - if not, it should remain invisible.

Comment: Oh! No I didn't. There's no adapter for the spinner at all. I didn't know it requires one. I'll go look up how to do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment by Pavel B., my problem was that I did not have an adapter for my spinner. In the XML I changed my menu item to use the default Spinner rather than my own custom layout, and then assigned the adapter in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` of my Activity.

**res/menu/menu_results.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
        android:title="@string/filter"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        app:showAsAction="always">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/iconHamburger"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:title="@string/options">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
                android:title="@string/settings"
                android:onClick="onMenuItemClick"></item>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/menu_logout"
                android:title="@string/log_out"
                android:onClick="onMenuItemClick"></item>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

**Activity.java**

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_results, menu);

        // Set up spinner menu item
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)menuItem.getActionView();
        String[] items={"All","Item1","Item2","Item3", "Item4"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,items);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return true;
    }
```

It shows up as:

[image: Spinner Menu Item]