# Adding a drop-down item in the action bar

Tags: android, kotlin, android-menu

I know the question was already asked here: [How to add a Dropdown item on the action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312344/how-to-add-a-dropdown-item-on-the-action-bar)

I'm trying to implement the solutions but can't figure out the Kotlin code to make it work. I'm sorry, I'm still new to Android development.

I created the overflow_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="haveri"
        yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner" />
</menu>
```

Then I'm trying to translate this code to Kotlin:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item); // get the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
```

I tried the following:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, menu)

    val item = menu?.findItem(R.id.spinner)
    val spinner = MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item) as (Spinner) // get the spinner

    spinner.adapter = adapter
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
}
```

But I don't understand what is the adapter here? Could someone please point me to the relevant documentation?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple adapter to use with spinner:

```
ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this,
        R.array.planets_array,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
).also { adapter ->
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.adapter = adapter
}
```

Add this to res/values/arrays.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
        <item>Jupiter</item>
        <item>Saturn</item>
        <item>Uranus</item>
        <item>Neptune</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

I took that code from the example in this official documentation:

Spinner: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner